# Accelerate image spinning on hover

Tags: html, css, css-transitions, css-animations

I got an image

```
<div class="spin-image">
    <img src="images/color-wheel.png" alt="" />
</div>
```

and its corresponding css

```
.spin-image {
  -webkit-animation:spin 10s linear infinite;
  -moz-animation:spin 10s linear infinite;
  animation:spin 10s linear infinite;

  -webkit-transition-duration: 2s; /* Safari */
  transition-duration: 2s;
}

.spin-image:hover {
  -webkit-animation:spin 2s linear infinite;
  -moz-animation:spin 2s linear infinite;
  animation:spin 2s linear infinite;
}

@-moz-keyframes spin { 100% { -moz-transform: rotate(360deg); } }
@-webkit-keyframes spin { 100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); } }
@keyframes spin { 100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); transform:rotate(360deg); } }
```

What I'm trying to do is to accelerate the image spinning on hover. The animation works, but the transition does not.

Comment: take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/a/18025979/1926369

Answer (score 1):

If you realise, this is like the animation and the hover animation are two different ones, and they reset to their virtual state of rotation in case they were running all the time you were or weren't hovering.
Unfortunatly, it is not posible to animate the transition between 2 different animation-durations.

Yet if you really really need a solution for this, you could program the animation using transition and a javascript interval that resets the positions for every turn. This way yo can reset the property and the duration of the transition at any time with javascript.

I made you a pen: http://codepen.io/vandervals/pen/aONmVL

This is the css you need:

```
.spin-image img{
  transition: transform 2s linear;
  transform: rotate(0deg);
}
.spin-image img.hover{
  transition: transform 1s linear;
}
```

And the JS:

```
var vel = 2000;
var degs = 0;
var cat = document.querySelector("img");
function repeat(){
  if(vel == 1000){
    cat.classList.add("hover");
    console.log("hover")
  }else{
    cat.classList.remove("hover");
    console.log("nohover")
  }
  degs+=360;
  cat.style.transform = "rotate("+degs+"deg)";
  setTimeout(repeat, vel);
}
repeat();
document.querySelector("img").addEventListener("mouseenter",hovering);
function hovering(){
  vel = 1000;
}
document.querySelector("img").addEventListener("mouseleave",nohovering);
function nohovering(){
  vel = 2000;
}
```

Comment: Your right but Why don't you use two classes. One as 
standard and one for the hove animation. that on hove remove the first class and add the class with the faster animation.