# CSS ease in and ease out on hover with infinite rotation

Tags: css, css-animations, css-transitions, css-transforms

I have some element that rotate on hover. How to add animation ease-in and ease-out, so  when cursor goes to element, it starts to rotate smoothly, an on mouse leave, stops smoothly.

```css
.sq {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  margin: 20px;
}
.sq1 {
  background-color: green;
  --c: 10deg;
  transform: rotate(var(--c));
}
.sq2 {
  background-color: blue;
  --c: 20deg;
  transform: rotate(var(--c));
}
.sq3 {
  background-color: rgb(128, 14, 103);
  --c: 60deg;
  transform: rotate(var(--c));
}
.sq:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  animation: rotation 1.3s infinite linear;
}

@keyframes rotation {
  from {
    transform: rotate(var(--c));
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(calc(360deg + var(--c)));
  }
}
```

```html
  <div>
    <div class="sq sq1"></div>
    <div class="sq sq2"></div>
    <div class="sq sq3"></div>
  </div>
```

Comment: You'd need JS to do that. A hover is a binary state so you can't transition out of it.

Comment: Take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18025979/1926369

Answer (score 0):

```css
.sq {
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    margin: 20px;
    transition: transform 1.6s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: transform 1.6s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: transform 1.6s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: transform 1.6s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: transform 1.6s ease-in-out;
}
  .sq1 {
    background-color: green;
    --c: 10deg;
    transform: rotate(var(--c));
    -webkit-transform: rotate(var(--c));
    -moz-transform: rotate(var(--c));
    -ms-transform: rotate(var(--c));
    -o-transform: rotate(var(--c));
}
  .sq2 {
    background-color: blue;
    --c: 20deg;
    transform: rotate(var(--c));
    -webkit-transform: rotate(var(--c));
    -moz-transform: rotate(var(--c));
    -ms-transform: rotate(var(--c));
    -o-transform: rotate(var(--c));
}
  .sq3 {
    background-color: rgb(128, 14, 103);
    --c: 60deg;
    transform: rotate(var(--c));
    -webkit-transform: rotate(var(--c));
    -moz-transform: rotate(var(--c));
    -ms-transform: rotate(var(--c));
    -o-transform: rotate(var(--c));
}
  .sq:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    transform: rotate(calc(360deg + var(--c)));
    -webkit-transform: rotate(calc(360deg + var(--c)));
    -moz-transform: rotate(calc(360deg + var(--c)));
    -ms-transform: rotate(calc(360deg + var(--c)));
    -o-transform: rotate(calc(360deg + var(--c)));
}
```

```html
<div>
        <div class="sq sq1"></div>
        <div class="sq sq2"></div>
        <div class="sq sq3"></div>
    </div>
```

Try these code

Comment: Thank You, but the square needs to rotate as long as mouse is over.